# How to have a Gitlab CI Pipeline run some jobs always and other jobs only on merge-requests?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, merge-request

**TL/DR:** 
My goal is to have a Gitlab (CE-12.4.2) pipeline that executes some jobs only on merge-requests and other jobs always (on merge-requests and on all normal pushes). How must the `.gitlab-ci.yml` look to do this?

**My use-case:** 
I have a big pipeline running a lot of jobs (tests, validation, dep's, build, doc's, ...). Now I have added a staging environment (using kubernetes) and have the pipeline build a new image and deploy that in the staging-environment. This allows me to instantly open up the changed (web-)application and see how the changes behave and look without having to check them out locally. Now building an image and deploying it to staging would be much too resource-heavy to do for every push, so I only want deployments to staging when someone creates a merge-request for me to review.

A very simplified example:

```
install:
  script: ...

test:
  script: ...

build-image:
  script: ...
  only: [merge_requests]

deploy-staging:
  script: ...
  only: [merge_requests]
```

For all normal pushes, the jobs `install` and `test` should be executed.

For merge-requests, the jobs `install`, `test`, `build-image` and `deploy-staging` should be executed.

**What i have tried:** Gitlab has this feature to define `only: [merge_requests]` on a job, this causes that job to only be executed when the pipeline is executed for a merge-request. Sounds like exactly what I am looking for, but there is a big catch. Once that attribute is applied to one job in a pipeline, all other jobs in that pipeline that do not have that attribute will be removed from the pipeline when executed inside merge-requests. That seemed like a bug to me at first, but is actually [documented behaviour](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#configuring-pipelines-for-merge-requests):

```
In the above example, the pipeline contains only a test job. Since the build and deploy jobs don’t have the only: [merge_requests] parameter, they will not run in the merge request.
```

In order to re-introduce all the other jobs to the pipeline for merge-requests, I have to apply `only: [merge_requests]` to all other jobs. The problem with that approach is that now these regular jobs do not get executed for normal git-pushes anymore. And I have no way to re-introduce these regular jobs to pipelines for normal pushes, because Gitlab has no support for `only: [always]` or anything like that.

Now I also have noticed that the `only` syntax is candidate for deprecation and one should prefer the `rules` syntax instead, so I took a look at that. There are multiple problems with that approach:

- The only way to detect with `rules` whether the pipeline is executed for a merge-request or not is to evaluate the variables related to merge-requests, like `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID`. Unfortunately these variables only exist when `only: [merge_requests]` is used, which would re-introduce the above problems.
- Rules only allow the conditional application of other attributes, so I still would have to use `only`, `except` or `when` attributes to actually remove or add jobs from or to the pipeline. Unfortunately Gitlab does not support anything like `only: [never]` or `when: never`, so i have no way to actually remove or add the jobs.

I also tried to have the jobs depend on another using `need` or `dependencies` attributes, this seemed to have no effect on whether the job is included to the pipeline or not.

The last thing I desperately tried was including all jobs always and just mark them as `when: manual` to be triggered manually by pushing a button. This somewhat works, but is very tedious because the deployment to staging is a multi-job process with every job taking quite some time to finish. So I would see a merge-request, push the button for the first job, wait 5 minutes, press the next button, wait 5 minutes again, and only then am able to use the staging. For many small merge-requests, this would take up a lot of my time and would not be a efficient solution. I also cannot just mark the first of these jobs as manual because Gitlab will then just skip that job and execute that later ones out of order (And again, `needs` and `dependencies` seem to have no effect on this when dealing with manually triggered jobs).

What i am a bit baffled about is that after searching the net, I have found nobody having the same problem. Either I am the only Gitlab User that wants to execute some jobs only for merge-requests without excluding all other jobs (which seems highly unlikely) or I am missing something obvious (which seems more likely). Am I missing something or does Gitlab really not support this use-case?

Comment: Just throwing this out there, could you use: `only: - merge_requests - pushes` for the normal push stages of `install` and `test`?

Comment: I feel your pain, you're not alone :/

Answer (score 6):

From the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803481/6309):

> But there is a problem. This example launches two pipelines for every push after MR is created. One for `only: [branch]`, one for `only: [merge_requests]`

Check if the last [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#use-both-branch-and-mr-pipelines-without-duplication) (January 2021) can help:

> ### Use both branch and MR pipelines without duplication
>
> Previously it was not possible to run pipelines for branches first, then switch to [merge requests pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/) when the MR is created.
>
> Consequently, with some configurations, a push to a branch could result in duplicate pipelines if a merge request was already open on the branch: one pipeline on the branch and another for the merge request.
>
> Now you can use the new `$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` predefined environment variable in your CI configurations to switch from branch pipelines to MR pipelines at the right time, and prevent redundant pipelines.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/yaml_example_avoid_duplicate_pipelines.png -- Use both branch and MR pipelines without duplication]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-environment-variables-reference) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201845).

[user2993689](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993689/user2993689) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801462/how-to-have-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline-run-some-jobs-always-and-other-jobs-only-on-mer/65864572?noredirect=1#comment123755163_65864572) to the documentation for a similar example:

> ### [Avoid duplicate pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines)

Comment: A similar example is given in the Gitlab documentation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines.

Comment: @user2993689 Thank you. I have included your comment to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The issue I have found with this solution is that it results in detached pipelines for pipelines triggered by a push to a MR, which I think is not what you'd expect if you pushed to a MR without `workflow` or `rules` in your config. I might be wrong, however.

Comment: @user2993689 Interesting. When you have figured it out, don't hesitate to edit directly this answer

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add some jobs to MR pipelines. I got example from here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#excluding-certain-jobs

General idea: you define `only: [branch, merge_requests]` for every job, and for deploy job rewrite it with `only: [merge_requests]`.

```
.only-default: &only-default
  only:
    - branches
    - merge_requests

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  <<: *only-default
  script:
    - echo build

deploy mr:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - build
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - echo "deploy on MR"
```

But there is a problem. This example launches two pipelines for every push after MR is created. One for `only: [branch]`, one for `only: [merge_requests]`. This is how `only: [merge_requests]` work, it launches job on every MR change. New commit is definitely a change.

It seems there is no solution which could launch pipeline ONLY for certain event - like MR creation.

But i think some workaround is posible:

1. Deploy staging job exsists for every pipeline
2. Job script checks if MR is created for current branch
3. If MR is created, script set label for this MR, like 'staging deployed'
4. If this label is already exsist, or MR is not created, just do nothing.

GitLab API, curl and jq can help with this. If i have some free time, I will definitely try to write it :).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

As described on the [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#use-rules-to-add-jobs) you have to configure your entrire pipeline to run in merge requests pipelines.

This can be achieved by adding following on top of the .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. The idea is to define a default for all CI jobs via the `workflow` keyword. Then for the CI job you'd want to run only on MRs, define a separate run (it overwrites the `workflow` rule for this job).

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"

install:
  script: ...

test:
  script: ...

build-image:
  script: ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"

deploy-staging:
  script: ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```