# Validate XML or JSON Schema through Gitlab YML Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In our project, we have create a repository. The repository has 100s of JSON and XML files. We have written XML and JSON Validators and define schema to validate XML and JSON files. Employee will update XML and JSON file and send merge requests. There are chances that they violate schema definitions. We would like to catch this and do not allow to merge such changes.

So, we are writing a Job - validate-schema. This job should validate Schema of all XML and JSON files against the Schema definition specified inside the repository.

Is there a way in Gitlab itself to do such validation? Otherwise, it seems we need to write a third party program to valid this schema and call then inside validate-schema job.

Comment: You mentioned "we have written XML and JSON validators" so why do you need a built-in GitLab validator?

Comment: Ideally the user doing the merge request has pre-validated for (1) XML or JSON correctness and (2) any schema definitions. Are you saying you want the "build" to fail if there's an issue, and that you're looking for something out of the box in gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the user doing the merge request has pre-validated for (1) XML or JSON correctness and (2) any schema definitions.

If you want the build/pipeline to fail if there's an issue, then you could consider running a gitlab 'job' at merge request time - this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801462/how-to-have-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline-run-some-jobs-always-and-other-jobs-only-on-mer?rq=1) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

High level, this will be a CI job that runs one of the JSON Schema validators. You can choose to either implement this as a shell script, using some of the command-line validators, or in Javascript, Python, or some of the other supported languages, as per https://json-schema.org/implementations

I choose to use a command-line tool, ajv-cli, to perform the validation itself.

In the top level directory, initialize node-js project and install ajv-cli and ajv-formats as dependencies

```
npm init
npm install ajv-cli ajv-formats --save
```

Then create the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
default:
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .npm/

validate:
  script:
    - npx ajv-cli validate -s schemas/my-schema.json -d document-to-validate.yaml -c ajv-formats
```

If you have more than one document to validate, you can run the `npx ajv-cli` command for each of them in a loop.